# Add delete characters when clicking on backspace

Tags: c++, string, console

I need to add code that deletes characters when clicking on backspace:

```cpp
double inputDoubleNumber() {
    double result = 0;
    int char_code;
    std::string buffer = "";
    bool dot = false;
    do {
        char_code = _getch();
        if (char_code > 47 && char_code < 58 || char_code == 46 ) {
            if (char_code == 46 && dot == true) continue;
            if (char_code == 46) dot = true;
            buffer += (char)char_code;
            std::wcout << (char)char_code;
        }
    } while (char_code != 13);
    std::wcout << std::endl;
    result = atof(buffer.c_str());
    return result;
}
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: This isn't a C function because it uses C++ types and objects, like `std::string` and `std::wcout`.

Comment: you want to remove the last entered character from the `buffer` when the user hits backspace?

Comment: why do you use `getch` and not `std::cin` ?

Comment: yes, I want delete last character from buffer

Comment: Please try to avoid [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notwithstanding the warning against using magic numbers, you can add the following block of code, immediately after the `_getch()` call:

```cpp
    if (char_code == '\b' && !buffer.empty()) { // Ignore B/S if buffer is empty
        if (buffer.back() == '.') dot = false;  // Need to check/reset "dot" flag
        buffer.pop_back();                      // remove last character...
        std::wcout << L'\b' << L' ' << L'\b';   //... and clear from screen
    }
```

Or, if you want to delete **all** input characters with **one hit** of the back-space key, you can use this, instead:

```cpp
   if (char_code == '\b') {
        dot = false;
        while (!buffer.empty()) {
            buffer.pop_back();
            std::wcout << L'\b' << L' ' << L'\b';
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about [using '\b' instead](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) of hard-coding the value?

Comment: @Christophe An excellent point (see edit). I couldn't recall the `\b` escape sequence at the time of first posting!